# redline under com.android.support:appcompat

Tags: android

I now have the following build.gradle Initially the `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` were set to 26 but I was getting a red line under

```
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.+'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.+'
```

I then chaged compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 27, the red lines for the above two lines went away but now I have a red line under the following line

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
```

Below is my current

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.future.edge"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'


    compile 'com.klinkerapps:android-smsmms:4.3.0'


    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.+'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

What do you need to do to get rid of the red line under it?

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'?
```

When I hover over it it says

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 27.0.2, 25.2.0. Examples include
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.0.2 and
>   com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.2.0 less... (Ctrl+F1) 
>   There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that
>   are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is
>   compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not
>   the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your
>   targetSdkVersion.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current version of com.android.support:appcompat is 27.1.0.
Try this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 27
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'
}
```

Also it's not the best practice to use notation like "27.0.+" to specify versions. You don't have control over versions so between builds you can get different implementations. Such change can affect your code and you won't know what is the source of the problem.

Edit:

The problem is here:

```
compile 'com.klinkerapps:android-smsmms:4.3.0'
```

you are including whole project which has it's own versions and you just can't mix them. Check inside of this repo for versions or just build this as .aar file and include as library to your project.

Comment: I'm still getting a red line under " implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'"

Comment: I've just tested it and it's working fine in my dummy project. Strange... Try to run File -> Invalidate Caches and Restart and/or rebuild the project.

Comment: Oh the smsmms lib seems to be a problem, see my edited answer